# Save and use information after page redirecting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have tables that are connected to each other. When the user clicks on settings icon, I find out how many connections does clicked table has, save that information and then redirect the page like this:

```
$("body").on('click', '.countconn', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var count;
    var id = $(this).closest('.foo').attr('id');
    count = $('#'+id+' .jtk-connected').length;
    location.href = "display.php";
});
```

I need to take that information about connections quantity to the new page. How do I do this without using ajax and PHP session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it via `URL` so it will be available in PHP script within `$_GET` variable:

`location.href = "display.php?connections="+count;`

Then in your PHP you can find it in `$_GET['connections']`